# face_recognition.py: Using multiple known images for face detection. IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, api, face-recognition

I am using the face_recognition.py api to find some known faces in a folder full of pictures. I have already tested my code with a single known face/image, but I am trying to do it with multiple faces.

But I keep getting the following error:
File "program.py", line 15, in 
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[counter]
IndexError: list index out of range

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
counter = 0
    for file in os.listdir(known_dir):
        image = face_recognition.load_image_file(known_dir+"/"+ file)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[counter]
        counter = counter+1
```

Please help me get rid of this error!

Comment: *counter* is greater than `face_recognition.face_encodings(image)`'s length. What is this loop supposed to do? Also take a look at [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Please in the future consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Is `face_encodings` initialized as a list by any chance? Maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
face_encodings = []
for file in os.listdir(known_dir):
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(known_dir+"/"+ file)
    face_encodings.append(face_recognition.face_encodings(image))
```

But than again, I can't really tell if that fixes the problem, since I can't test it...